# Supabase StorageApiError: The resource was not found when using download

Tags: javascript, postgresql, svelte, supabase

I'm having some issues accessing a private bucket in Supabase.

Here is the bucket policy as suggested by the Supabase docs [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/access-control):

```
create policy "Public Access download something"
on storage.objects
for select                              -- Allow read access
to authenticated                  -- Allow access to authenticated users
using ( bucket_id = 'downloads' );   -- Identify the bucket
```

And on my Svelte component I'm trying to do this (just testing to see what is going on) as suggested by the Supabase docsL [here](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-download)

```js
 supabase.storage
        .from('downloads')
        .download('test.zip')
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
```

I used the policy for the storage in the dashboard like so:
[image]
and the output was the following:

```
CREATE POLICY "Download policy lpjtgr_0" ON storage.objects FOR SELECT TO authenticated 
USING (bucket_id = 'downloads');
```

and Whenever I try to access this file using the download method as shown above I keep getting this error:

StorageApiError: The resource was not found at http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-54QQGXCG.js?v=40707935:115:14

"StorageApiError"
status: 400
__isStorageError: true
message: "The resource was not found"

but the file and bucket are clearly there...Any ideas on what's going on? And yes, of course my user is authenticated before trying this test :)

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your bucket so that we can see the file stored in the correct location?